# VM heartbeat problem

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

I created a VM heartbeat alarm on a cluster with ESX 3.5U4 Servers and everything worked as expected.

After an upgrade to ESXi 4.0 U1 the alarm is now always bouncing between green and yellow. This happens on all VMs in the cluster
(Linux and Windows) and with old or new VMware tools.
When I move the VM back to a 3.5 host, the bouncing stops.

The vCenter version is 4.0U1

Since the status is also logged in hostd.log, it looks like a problem between the host and the VM, but where ?

Here is an example of a hostd.log from an ESX server:

```
--2010-01-20 13:47:04.320 27A36B90 verbose 'vm:/vmfs/volumes/.../test/test.vmx'-- Updating current heartbeatStatus: yellow
--2010-01-20 13:47:44.322 27AF9B90 verbose 'vm:/vmfs/volumes/.../test/test.vmx'-- Updating current heartbeatStatus: green
--2010-01-20 13:48:04.322 27B7BB90 verbose 'vm:/vmfs/volumes/.../test/test.vmx'-- Updating current heartbeatStatus: yellow
--2010-01-20 13:48:44.325 27AB8B90 verbose 'vm:/vmfs/volumes/.../test/test.vmx'-- Updating current heartbeatStatus: green
--2010-01-20 13:49:04.327 27AF9B90 verbose 'vm:/vmfs/volumes/.../test/test.vmx'-- Updating current heartbeatStatus: yellow
--2010-01-20 13:49:44.327 27B7BB90 verbose 'vm:/vmfs/volumes/.../test/test.vmx'-- Updating current heartbeatStatus: green
--2010-01-20 13:50:04.329 27B7BB90 verbose 'vm:/vmfs/volumes/.../test/test.vmx'-- Updating current heartbeatStatus: yellow
--2010-01-20 13:50:44.331 27A36B90 verbose 'vm:/vmfs/volumes/.../test/test.vmx'-- Updating current heartbeatStatus: green
--2010-01-20 13:51:04.334 10799B90 verbose 'vm:/vmfs/volumes/.../test/test.vmx'-- Updating current heartbeatStatus: yellow
--2010-01-20 13:51:44.336 27BBCB90 verbose 'vm:/vmfs/volumes/.../test/test.vmx'-- Updating current heartbeatStatus: green
--2010-01-20 13:52:04.338 27A77B90 verbose 'vm:/vmfs/volumes/.../test/test.vmx'-- Updating current heartbeatStatus: yellow
```

Comment: Can you give us a rough idea of the network setup - specifically what vSwitches and Port Groups have you got for Service Console\Kernel and VM's on the ESX 3.5 box(es) and what Management Port \ VM Port groups have you got on the ESXi box(es).

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the fact that you can move them back to ESX 3.5, I am guessing you haven't upgraded the VM hardware to the newest version. I would upgrade the hardware and vmware tools. I don't believe the heartbeat is network related, but rather vmware tools related.

Comment: We have seen this behavior after an upgrade from 3.5 to 4.0 when the hardware was not upgraded to v7. So yes, could definitely be the cause. That said, upgrading the virtual hardware is a one-way trip (short of running the VM back through VMWare convertor or attaching the disks to a new VMX). Try this with a test VM before you do it with anything important.